# No adapter attached but already set on fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have encountered this so many times before but this time it's kinda frustrating. I already change the order of attachiing the adapter: setLayoutManager first; observe the viewmodel first; nothing worked. the viewmodel function is not being observed either. here's my code:

```
class FavoriteMoviesFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = FavoriteMoviesFragment()
}

private val viewModel: FavoriteMoviesViewModel by viewModels()
private var favmovieAdapter = MoviesAdapter(object : MovieClickListener {
    override fun onMovieClicked(movie: Movies?) {
        viewModel.onMovieClicked(movie)
    }
})

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvFavMovies)
    Log.d("favAdapter", "Adapter attached $favmovieAdapter")
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView?.adapter = favmovieAdapter
    vmSetup()
    return inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.favorite_movies_fragment,
        container, false
    )
}

fun vmSetup() {
    viewModel.getFavMovies().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { movielist ->
        if (movielist != null) {
            Log.d("pagedFavList", "List size: ${movielist.size}")
            favmovieAdapter.submitList(movielist)
            favmovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Loading Always Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
    viewModel.navigatetoDetail().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { movies ->
        if (movies != null) {
            val action =
                FavoriteFragmentDirections.actionFavoriteFragmentToDetailFragment(movies, null)
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)
            viewModel.onMovieDetailNavigated()
        }
    })
}
```

any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Try setting the favmovieAdapter in the onCreateView method?

Comment: already done it, the error still occuring @FaisalKarim

Comment: "Log.d("pagedFavList", "List size: ${movielist.size}")" move this line above if() condition to check observer is observing or not.@RizkyPutraPradhanaBudiman

Comment: unfortunately the observer is not observing either @androidLearner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. You are trying to find the recycleview adapter from a view before inflating it. so

```
view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvFavMovies)
```

just returns null. Therefore, everything after it just becomes null.

instead, try this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_favorite_movies,
        container, false
    )


    val recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvFavMovies)
    Log.d("favAdapter", "Adapter attached $favmovieAdapter")
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView?.adapter = favmovieAdapter
    vmSetup()
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use adapter.observe{} function. Inside observe you can put notify data changed.

You can fine more information about this in

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata